# Is ChiSquarePValue from Hypothesis testing package incorrect?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, packages

```
Needs["HypothesisTesting`"];

ChiSquarePValue[2/10, 1]
```

gives `OneSidedPValue -> 0.345279`

whereas

```
N@1 - CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[1], x] /. x ->
  2/10
```

Gives `0.654721` (which I believe is the correct value)

Is this a bug, or is the package just outdated?

Also, are such packages user created and uploaded? It is not clear to me (it has a page on the wolfram website)

Comment: welcome to MSE. The "HypothesisTesting" package is from Wolfram. I think that this is an error relating degree of freedom 1: I note that: `ChiSquarePValue[x, 1]` yields: `Min[GammaRegularized[1/2, x/2], GammaRegularized[1/2, 0, x/2]]`. However, `Integrate[E^(-x/2)/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[x]), {x, a, Infinity}]` and `SurvivalFunction[ChiSquareDistribution[1], x]` yield correct results. I think you should feedback to Wolfram. I am happy to be corrected.

Comment: It depends on your definition of a *P*-value.  The documentation for `ChiSquarePValue` states "The one-sided p-value is CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[df],x] if x is less than the median of the \[Chi]^2 distribution with df degrees of freedom, and 1-CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[df],x] otherwise."  So you might have a beef with Wolfram about the definition but not the calculation.